# How to deal with client turn off Javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, client-server

I am concerning about client who turns off Javascript in their browser for security reasons. My web application use jQuery heavily on validation, AJAX, etc.

My colleague suggests I also do the validation on server side. But I also have some show/hide effect on client side, for example, if a checkbox is checked, a hiden table will show immediately. I know with setting `autopostback = true`, I can also get the same effect.
However, is there no conflict?

I don't know how many client browsers don't support Javascript. My colleage also said someone could modify javascript to bypass validation. With the session velidation on server side, is this kind of hack possible, is this meaningful? My web application is .net 3.5 project. I just don't know how to convince him. Any suggestion is hignly appreciated!

Comment: Server side validation is **always** more secure than doing it on the client side. Anybody can turn off Javascript, enter malicious data, and then submit it to the server without it being checked. Always assume the worst-case when dealing with user input.

Comment: Hackers aren't going to use your form to submit data to your server.  They'll use their own methods.  Server-side validation is a 100% must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must always perform validation on the server when dealing with posted forms.  Consider - I can craft a small script in PHP and `POST` data to your server without using your form at all!  You cannot ever rely on javascript validation.

Javascript validation is like the icing on the cake.  It can make your form more accessible and more easy to understand.  But it just isn't the cake itself.  Take some time to read about the concept of "progressive enhancement":

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/22/progressive-enhancement-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it/

For javascript-heavy web applications, though, sometimes progressive enhancement isn't worth it.  For instance, if I am making a web-based payment processing system for a specific in-house use.  I know there will be Firefox, I know who will be using it.  If anyone tries to use it outside the known environment, I don't care that it doesn't work - they aren't supposed to be using it.  Likewise, if I'm creating a complex browser-based image editing web application, there just won't be any point in a non-javascript version of the application.

You've got to assess whether your final product aims to be accessible by the largest segment of users, or if the features brought by javascript are important and specific enough to merit **requiring** javascript in order to use your application.  In those cases, check out the `noscript` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/noscript

Answer (score 1):

You should certainly use server-side validation, always. It is easy to bypass client-side validation if you know what you're doing.

As for dealing with users who disable JavaScript, you could do something like have a lightbox style window above all of your content, with a message such as "Please enable JavaScript", and then remove the lightbox with JavaScript when the page loads.

These days however, the vast majority of users will have JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 0):

That's the reason why you should always perform validation on the server. If the client has javascript disabled you will be guaranteed that whatever he enters will be correctly validated before processing it.

Answer (score 0):

Always, always validate on the server side.  Client-side validation is for the user's convenience only.

However, regarding disabled JavaScript.  If it is important to you then write in pure HTML/CSS.  In the vast majority of web applications, JavaScript is a standard part of the application logic.  You don't need to account for user's who disabled JavaScript.. it simply is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You should always do validation on the server, due to the issues you mention; javascript turned off or modified.

Note that many of the auto post back abilities also use Javascript, so much of that won't work, either. You'll have to decide how you want to proceed there. Likely just presenting everything, and having the server filter out inappropriate things for their selections.

You might use a `<noscript>` element to inform the user that the form in question is not designed for non-javascript browsers, and strongly encourage them to enable it. You can even hide the whole form by default and only show it in the `Ready()` function, so it only works with javascript, basically. (keeping in mind you are still validating everything server-side to account for malicious modifications)

Answer (score 0):

> My colleage also said someone could modify javascript to bypass validation. With the session velidation on server side, is this kind of hack possible, is this meaningful?

You are confusing validation with session/authentication.  One has nothing to do with the other.  And yes, modifying (or completely disabling) JavaScript gets around client side validation.  You should consider client side validation something to *help* the user.  It should not be relied on for your business logic, since it can be tampered with.

So, server-side validation is also a must.

If you really-really want to make sure the client takes advantage of the niceties of your client side validation, use a 'noscript' block to let them know "hey, JavaScript is disabled.  For an improved user experience, please re-enable JavaScript"